# Strange results with groupby, transform, and NaNs

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

**Edit (19-May-2015):**  I just verified that this has been fixed as of version 0.16.1 so this should not be a problem in up to date versions.

These ought to all give the same results, right?

```
df.groupby(level=0).transform('mean')
df.groupby(level=0)['x'].transform(np.nanmean)
df.groupby(level=0)['x'].transform('mean')
```

First two are OK, but third does not work.  Might be a bug?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':[1,np.nan,3,4] }, index=[1,1,2,2],)

df
Out[686]: 
    x
1   1
1 NaN
2   3
2   4

df.groupby(level=0).transform('mean')
Out[687]: 
     x
1  1.0
1  1.0
2  3.5
2  3.5

df.groupby(level=0)['x'].transform(np.nanmean)
Out[688]: 
1    1.0
1    1.0
2    3.5
2    3.5
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

That's all good, but not this:

```
df.groupby(level=0)['x'].transform('mean')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-691-24761ee742fd> in <module>()
----> 1 df.groupby(level=0)['x'].transform('mean')

C:\Users\eilerj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in transform(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   2411         # if string function
   2412         if isinstance(func, compat.string_types):
-> 2413             return self._transform_fast(lambda : getattr(self, func)(*args, **kwargs))
   2414 
   2415         # do we have a cython function

C:\Users\eilerj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in _transform_fast(self, func)
   2457         values = np.repeat(values, com._ensure_platform_int(counts))
   2458 
-> 2459         return self._set_result_index_ordered(Series(values))
   2460 
   2461     def filter(self, func, dropna=True, *args, **kwargs):

C:\Users\eilerj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in _set_result_index_ordered(self, result)
    495             result = result.sort_index()
    496 
--> 497         result.index = self.obj.index
    498         return result
    499 

C:\Users\eilerj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   1978         try:
   1979             object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 1980             return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   1981         except AttributeError:
   1982             pass

C:\Users\eilerj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__set__ (pandas\lib.c:38795)()

C:\Users\eilerj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in _set_axis(self, axis, labels, fastpath)
    266         object.__setattr__(self, '_index', labels)
    267         if not fastpath:
--> 268             self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
    269 
    270     def _set_subtyp(self, is_all_dates):

C:\Users\eilerj\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
   2209         if new_len != old_len:
   2210             raise ValueError('Length mismatch: Expected axis has %d elements, '
-> 2211                              'new values have %d elements' % (old_len, new_len))
   2212 
   2213         self.axes[axis] = new_labels

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

Comment: I think this is a bug, which I should have fixed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9699).  Could you check with trunk pandas to confirm?

Comment: @DSM Sorry, I don't know how to check trunk pandas.  This is with latest pandas (16.0) but it looks like you might have fixed it only a few days ago.  I'll leave this up for now but if I should delete the question just let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report, and would better as a Github issue (although this happens to already fixed!). :)

Comment: @Andy Hayden  I don't know if it's better to close or delete, but am happy to delete if that helps.  Let me know.

Comment: @JohnE no problem, I "voted to close" so it takes 5 people to agree then it stays around, but kinda labels it as "doesn't have an answer". Don't delete it - keep your upvotes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified that this has indeed been fixed in version 0.16.1.  See comments above by @DSM and @AndyHayden.